# How does one hook dynamic AJAX content into an array with two way model binding -anguljarjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm using [dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dropzone.js/info) to upload images to my application. I want the generated previews to be angularjs compatible so that I can do things with the images based off of the scope variables. Every image I upload I want to be inserted into the master photo array and map everything in the photo preview element to the object in the photo array.

I hook into the dropzone event for adding the file and then compile the template to make it angular js compatible. The problem is now I'm not sure how to hook that image set to an array in the scope, since I'm not doing anything with an ng-repeat etc with an index.

How can I tell and associate the content generated from dropzone with the angularjs objects in the scope array?

The dropzone complete function:

```
this.on("complete", function (file) {
    //Stop the loading icon.
    file.previewElement.querySelector(".loader").style.display = 'none';

    //Compile all angular items.
    compileAngularElement(file.previewElement, "PhotoController");
});
```

The template:

```
<div id="template" class="gallery-template-base">
    <div class="gallery-thumb mb-lg">
    <img data-dz-thumbnail>
    <a class="remove-image" data-dz-remove href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="mark-featured" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    </a>
    <span class="loader">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div style="display:none;" class="alert alert-danger" data-dz-errormessage>
</div>                                        
</div>
```

**Edit With More Code**

The angular controller is basically nothing at the moment:

```
RRAngular.controller('PhotoController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.Photos = [];
        }]);
```

The photos array is what I want to fill. I want to make an object like { photoName: "filename", photoID: 44} and fill the array with that. My question is how do I associate the created object with the preview element generated my dropzone. If I change the photoName of the first element in the array, I only want the first image photoname to change.

```
Dropzone.options.photoDropzone = {
            paramName: "UploadedImage", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 10, // MB
            thumbnailWidth: 300,
            thumbnailHeight: 169,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
            previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
            init: function () {
                this.on('error', function (file, errorMessage) {
                    //Show the error box.
                    file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-errormessage]").style.display = 'block';
                });
                this.on("success", function (file, responseData) {
                    //Set up the ajax data for the file.
                    SetupPhotoTemplate(file.previewElement, responseData.ResultObject.property_photo_id, responseData.ResultObject.photo_order);
                });
                this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                    //Start the loading icon.
                    file.previewElement.querySelector(".loader").style.display = 'block';
                });
                this.on("complete", function (file) {
                    //Stop the loading icon.
                    file.previewElement.querySelector(".loader").style.display = 'none';

                    //Compile all angular items.
                    compileAngularElement(file.previewElement, "PhotoController");
                });

            }
        };
```

You can see on the complete function I take the template element I provided above and compile it. At this point I would want to do something like $scope.photos.Add(MYPHOTOOBJECT) and have the values in that object bind to the template. I don't know how to associate that particular template with the object in the array.

**Edit 2**

The compile angular function is as follows:

```
//A function that allows one to compule angular elements after the page loads. Typically used with ajax content.
function compileAngularElement(elSelector, controllerID) {    
    // The new element to be added
    if (elSelector !== null) {
        var $div = $(elSelector);

        // The parent of the new element
        var $target = $("[ng-app]");

        angular.element($target).injector().invoke(['$compile', function ($compile) {
            var $scope = angular.element($target).scope();
            //var $scope = angular.element(document.getElementById(controllerID)).scope();
            $compile($div)($scope);
            // Finally, refresh the watch expressions in the new element
            $scope.$apply();
        }]);
    }
}
```

I want to point out that the issue/question isn't really related to dropzone. The question is how can I associate one of the preview elements with an element in the scope array.

To try and explain it again in text, if I put in the preview element {{FileName}} and then I have an array looking like this on the scope [{FileName:"cookie"}, {FileName:"food"}, {FileName:"foobar"}], how do I get cookie to fill in {{FileName}} in the first preview and food in the second {{FileName}}.

As of now, if I put {{FileName}} and assign it in scope, every preview is going to have the same filename displayed.

Comment: Where is the dropzone completed function actually implemented and what's in your controller?

Comment: I am sorry maybe my bad, but I can't understand very well your question. Are you asking how to pass something inside AngularJS from something that you get outside AngularJS? And I don't see any AngularJS controller here or whatever

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Consider using the methodology of  [ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone).

Comment: @MikeFeltman I updated the question to hopefully clarify. Quirimmo, I'm asking how to associate the jquery template that was generated via dropzone with an angularjs array.I don't know how to associate the template div with an object in a scope array so that the model binding like filename shows.

Comment: What is the source of the `compileAngularElement` function?

Comment: @georgeawg Edited it again with that. The question is more about angularjs though than dropzone. I've added text trying to explain it again.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you're going to use 3rd party elements like this with Angularjs you'd wrap them in a module and inject the module. I'm not familiar with dropdown.js but I would think the way to deal with this is to have the method it communicates with be a method in the controller so that within it you have access to the controller.

I'm assuming this is Bootstrap's dropdown you are trying to implement. It's not generally recommended to try to use the native bootstrap components with Angular and integration is often very challenging. The angular team has created a whole set of replacement components for these that are available here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ If this is indeed the case, I'd really recommend you utilize this.

Comment: The [dropdown.js homepage](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). The [FAQ on Github](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

Comment: Check my edit. My question isn't really dropzone related.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I saw dropdown.js in the title and went off researching based on that. A quick google of dropzone.js angularjs reveals several directives for this, as well as a video: https://www.google.com/search?q=dropzone+js+angularjs. I looked at this directive:  https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone and it provides a module like I advocated for above. I still think using a module is the way to go.